# Duplicate Multiple Children Independently in a GridView

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

This app I am coding to learn Flutter/Dart has a flat button that generates a random number in a set range, a text widget to show said number, and a flat button when pressed resets the text widget to 0.

I am trying to add a a floating action button that when pressed will add a new set of of buttons and text widget mentioned above under the existing one that will be able to generate a new independent random number without altering the previous one. Am looking to find a way to be able to add as many as I want all  being able to generate random numbers independently. Thanks!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' show Random;

    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          //title: 'Random Number Generator',
          //theme: ThemeData(
          //primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          //visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          //),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Random Number Increase'),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

      final String title;

      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    int min = 50;
    int max = 250;
    var rnd = Random();

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      int _counter = 0;

      void _incrementCounter() {
        setState(() {
          _counter = min + rnd.nextInt(max - min);
        });
      }

      void _resetCounter() {
        setState(() {
          _counter = 0;
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        final double itemHeight = (size.height - kToolbarHeight - 550) / 2;
        final double itemWidth = size.width / 2;

        return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
                body: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        colors: [Colors.orange, Colors.orange],
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: GridView.count(
                      primary: true,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 100,
                      ),
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          child: FlatButton(
                              child: Text('Random',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                  )),
                              color: Colors.green,
                              onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                              splashColor: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            '$_counter',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: FlatButton(
                            child: Text('Reset',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                )),
                            color: Colors.red,
                            onPressed: _resetCounter,
                            splashColor: Colors.yellow,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ))));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, a few hints. Instead of a single _counter, maintain a List<int> of counters for your rows. And take a look at dart generator functions or Iterable.map to create your widgets on demand.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, feel like I'm still working my way to implement these things but from a cursory look seems like good steps to doing what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andrew, what's making your life harder is the fact you want a logic for each row (3 elements in the grid) and keeping individual state for each of them.

Thus the Grid with individual components is not that dynamic as you'd like to have.

The easiest solution would be to separate the logic component with its individual counter, reset and random buttons as a separate widget (`RowCounter`), `Row` based, and add a `ListView` instead of `GridView` to render a list of them dynamically.

Another fix is that you probably tested this solution with only one screen size, but your itemHeight can become negative according to the device size you use (if the height is less than `kToolbarHeight + 550`, so I removed the sizes for you to fix them yourself (I've commented those lines)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' show Random;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //title: 'Random Number Generator',
      //theme: ThemeData(
      //primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      //visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      //),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Random Number Increase'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

int min = 50;
int max = 250;
var rnd = Random();

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<RowCounter> counterList = [RowCounter()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void _incrementCounter() {
      setState(() {
        counterList.add(RowCounter());
      });
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _incrementCounter,
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              colors: [Colors.orange, Colors.orange],
            ),
          ),
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
            children: <Widget>[...counterList],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RowCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RowCounterState createState() => _RowCounterState();
}

class _RowCounterState extends State<RowCounter> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter = min + rnd.nextInt(max - min);
    });
  }

  void _resetCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter = 0;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    // double itemHeight = (size.height - kToolbarHeight - 550) / 2;
    // double itemWidth = size.width / 2;

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          // height: itemHeight,
          // width: itemWidth,
          child: FlatButton(
              child: Text('Random',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  )),
              color: Colors.green,
              onPressed: _incrementCounter,
              splashColor: Colors.white),
        ),
        Container(
          // height: itemHeight,
          // width: itemWidth,
          child: Text(
            '$_counter',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        Container(
          // height: itemHeight,
          // width: itemWidth,
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text('Reset',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                )),
            color: Colors.red,
            onPressed: _resetCounter,
            splashColor: Colors.yellow,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and explanation. Understand the logic and figuring out the syntax now. Good point out on the screen size.

Comment: Welcome, @AndrewCaprario
Glad for helping